# How can I force a media rescan on Lollipop?

Tags: root-access, mtp

I would like to force a rescan so that the MTP file listing is correct when I use Android File Transfer on my Mac.

I've tried a half dozen apps but none of them seem to work on Android 5.0.

I have rooted my device.

Comment: Unmount and mount your SD card

Comment: There is no SD card on a Nexus 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try heading over to the Settings>Apps>All, Look out for Gallery app, tap over it and Clear Data and the Cache Stored.

Comment: Once I've done this how do I refresh the cache? If I follow these instructions and then connect to a computer I can't access **any files**.

Comment: Hey @Venko did you followed the method I have guided you ?? I am not getting the cache refresh thing because once you clear the cache and the data it automatically refresh the cache ! So, there's not need to do that manually and about your PC can't access any files you need to make sure that all the device drivers are installed and if that still doesn't shows thing then you can also try changing the connecting like to MTP or Portable camera.